# SELECT date greater than today

Tags: php, mysql

Right now I have the following query:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * from training ORDER BY startDate ASC LIMIT 4');
```

Then, I process it further like this:

```
if($row['endDate'] > $today && $row['status'] != '2')
```

How can I combine the `if` statement into the db query? I'm not sure how to check the `endDate` and compare it to today's date in the query.

Comment: Use a [WHERE clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html) in your database query

Comment: and `SYSDATE()` or `NOW()` to get current date.

Comment: @MarkBaker Understood, but how do I check the current date and compare it to the endDate?

Comment: `WHERE \`endDate\` > NOW() AND \`status\` <> 2`.... [MySQL Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @MarkBaker

Comment: Did something go wrong when you tried to access the MySQL manual, or read your MySQL book? This is really basic stuff that you should be researching yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just:

```
"SELECT * from training 
 WHERE endDate > '$today' 
 AND status != 2 
 ORDER BY startDate ASC LIMIT 4"
```

works if endDate is a DATE orSTRING field. Or $today is like '2015-15-01' eg date('Y-m-d');

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a totally different set of results; since you were limiting your query and then filtering it, it would be quite probable to get no valid results. Since you are now filtering the results of the entire table, there are many more potential matches to choose from.

Also you specifically mentioned "today's *date*", so that it what this is comparing against.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare(
    "SELECT * from training 
    WHERE endDate > CURDATE() AND status != 2 
    ORDER BY startDate ASC LIMIT 4"
);
```